# Swift: flatMap to Dictionary

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, ios9, flatmap

I am trying to parse the following JSON:

```
{ 
  "String For Key 1": [
    "Some String A",
    "Some String B",
    "Some String C",
  ],
  "String For Key 2": [
    "Some String D",
    "Some String E",
    "Some String F"
  ],
  "String For Key 3": [
    "Some String G",
    "Some String H",
    "Some String I",
  ],
  "String For Key 4": [
    "Some String J",
    "Some String K",
    "Some String L"
  ],
  "String For Key 5": [
    "Some String M",
    "Some String N",
    "Some String O"
  ],
  "String For Key 6": [
    "Some String P",
    "Some String Q",
    "Some String R"
  ]
}
```

I am also following this [tutorial](https://github.com/objcio/S01E01-networking).  It's on Github in Playground

In the example, they are parsing an `Array` of dictionaries using `typealias JSONDictionary = [String: AnyObject]`

I need to parse a `Dictionary` that has a `Key` which is `String`, and `Value` that is an `Array`. Hence: `typealias JSONDictionary = [String: [AnyObject]]` and I am getting an error when returning a `flatMap`.

```
extension Resource {
    init(url: NSURL, parseJSON: AnyObject -> A?) {
        self.url = url
        self.parse = { data in
            let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String: [AnyObject]]
           //This is where I get an error
            return json.flatMap(parseJSON)
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot convert value of type `AnyObject -> A? to expected argument type `([String: [AnyObject]]?) -> _?
```

How can I get a dictionary with `Keys` as `String` and `Values` as an `Array`?  I would like to keep their `Generic` approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type of jsonString is `Dictionary<String, Array<String>>`
You can give it a type like `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`

AnyObject can contain class and struct i.e `Array`, `Dictionary`, `String`, `Int`, Obj C Classes 
Hence an `Array<String>` is represented by `AnyObject` **not** `[AnyObject]`

```
let jsonString:[String: AnyObject] =
[
    "String For Key 1": [
    "http://www.urlToSomePathA.jpg",
    "http://www.urlToSomePathB.jpg",
    "http://www.urlToSomePathC.jpg",
    ],
    "String For Key 2": [
    "http://www.urlToSomePathD.jpg",
    "http://www.urlToSomePathE.jpg",
    "http://www.urlToSomePathF.jpg"
    ]
]

// Now you can map a function on the value type
let values = jsonString.flatMap { $0.1 as? [String] }
print(values)
// RESULT: [["http://www.urlToSomePathA.jpg", "http://www.urlToSomePathB.jpg", "http://www.urlToSomePathC.jpg"], ["http://www.urlToSomePathD.jpg", "http://www.urlToSomePathE.jpg", "http://www.urlToSomePathF.jpg"]]
```

**Update**

```
let keys = jsonString.flatMap { $0.0 } // ["String For Key 1", "String For Key 2"]
```

As commented by @dffri, you can use keys property on dictionary which will return `LazyMapCollection` which will realise only if you access the object inside.

```
let keys = jsonString.keys
```

Comment: Thanks.  This doesn't print the `keys`?  How do I get the keys as a `key` and `value` as `Array`?

Comment: @user1107173 I have updated the answer, you can get to keys by `let keys = jsonString.flatMap { $0.0 }`

Comment: Note: no need to use `flatMap` for the keys, as there is no attempted casting there (just `let keys = jsonString.map{ $0.0 }` suffices). Alternatively, use the `keys` property of a dictionary to get the keys as a lazy collection: `let keys = jsonString.keys`.

Comment: Wait.  Please note in my question, I have a dictionary that I am trying to parse, not an array.  In your answer, jsonString is an Array.

Comment: @user1107173, jsonString is Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

Comment: @user1107173. you can get to the Type via, `print((Mirror(reflecting: jsonString)).subjectType)`

Comment: Sorry, I am confused.  First, thank you for your patience and help!  Second, your jsonString starts out with an array `[`, while my json starts with a dictionary `{`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If it helps, here is a link to a sample project I created.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vhbwvei4h6vxyif/AABxi0FSwM9aaOuYN00Dbau2a?dl=0

Comment: @user1107173, you have posted json as String, when you serialise it with `NSJSONSerialization` and cast as `[String: AnyObject]`, you will get what I have answered as. `Dictionary` is denoted by `[:]`, where as `Array` by `[]`. Notice the **colon** in between parenthesis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120353/discussion-between-user1107173-and-k-nimo).